# 'str' object is not callable when trying to set object property

Tags: python, properties

Having such object

```
class testDec(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 'stuff'
    @property
    def x(self):
        print 'called getter'
        return self.__x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print 'called setter'
        self.__x = value
```

Why I can not set attribute `__x` ? Here is a traceback

```
>>> a.x
called getter
'stuff'
>>> a.x(11)
called getter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm using 2.7.6 Python

Comment: If you're trying to set `a.x`, shouldn't you be doing `a.x = 11`?

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for properties looks like normal attribute access (by design).

It's the main use case of the property decorator, for creating "managed attributes" precisely so that you don't have to use function call syntax for getters and setters:

- `a.x()` just becomes `a.x`
- `a.x(11)` just becomes `a.x = 11`

Ergo:

```
>>> a = testDec()
>>> a.x
called getter
'stuff'
>>> a.x = 123
called setter
>>> a.x
called getter
123
```

This is all documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

*Note:* usually in python you would store the "unmanaged" attribute as `self._x`, not `self.__x`.